# Refactor SFDC data model?

Tags: developer, architecture

I recently joinged a 400+ SF users  company as architect. I observed previous implementation were not as per best practices and lead to bad data quality and Insights. I have been asked by business to  refactor our existing SF data model as there are existing tech debt associated with it. I am planning to remove/hide/delete fields -object by object. As there are around 200 fields, its taking too long to refactor due to impact analysis/regression testing for each fields as we've lot of process builders, configuration built in. Is there a better and faster way to to refactor the data model ?

Comment: The free Field Trip app may help you in this process, as might the forthcoming Dependency API. In the meantime, there's always metadata pull + full text search. But I don't think there is a direct answer to your question. Addressing technical debt is a Hard Problem.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is broad one and doesn't provide any specific issues.

Here are few points to be noted for impact analysis and redesign.

1. Understand existing business model and why those objects, fields and process builder's process have been created. You need to go through each and every field and to find impact of removing those. If the field is used in trigger, process or workflow then until those are removed from them, you cannot remove those.
2. If there are data quality issues then find out which system is source of truth. If any data is loaded from external system then those external data qualities to be revisited.

If the data is solely created and used inside Salesforce then `validation rule` will help to reduce data inconsistency.

Use of `Duplicate Management` will govern the data quality issues.

3. Environment to be finalized for impact analysis. It is preferable to investigate in `Full Copy` sandbox which should be refreshed from production.
4. Usually for insert or update operation, one of the following can be used:
   Trigger, Process Builder, Workflow rule, Flow.

So, you need to think about designing proposed system such a way, the same process or attributes must not be updated many times using more than one way using above.

Finally, there could be other things to be investigated like Sharing & Visibility, performance etc., so I can say, it is not about Data Model to revisit, you need look everything and entire system.